# Google custom search customization

Tags: google-custom-search

I need my custom search engine to search specific page of the websites.
Here is an example. I wanted to search "contact Us' Page of every indexed website in google search engine? Is this possibe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. You can provide the URL to your search engine like:
*www.example.com/ContactUs*.

If you want to know more about this URL patters, go through the link,and you can find some sample URL patterns.
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/71826?hl=en